# Rails - Execute javascript code on cancan access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

Let's say I have a rescue code on my application controller for handling access denied from cancan, like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    #handle the exception
  end

end
```

What I would like to do is, when the exception is raised, to show a popup to the user. But for that I should run a javascript code. How could I achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need JavaScript code to do that, not Ruby. A redirect (HTTP 302) has no ability to run JavaScript.

Comment: @tadman yeah, I made it clear in the question that I need to run a javascript code. But the problem is that I need to run that when the exception is raised (that happens on server side). So I would like to know how could I do that

Comment: The only thing Rails can do is produce HTTP responses and a redirect cannot contain JavaScript. You could try making an AJAX (XHR) call and returning JSON which JavaScript in the client interprets and responds to. That way you have full control over the actions in the browser.

Comment: @tadman that's what I thought... wish there was an easier way to do that. Thank you so much, anyway!